# Search Infragistics WebDataGridView recursively for a GroupField by a GroupField key

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am working on a project where I need to add a BoundDataField to a GroupField. I know what the data field name is, and I know the key of the GroupField I want to add the BoundDataField to, but I don't know if the group exists.

What I need to therefore do, is search the WebDataGridView for the GroupField by key, and if it exists add the BoundDataField to GroupField, and if the GroupField doesn't exists, I need to add the GroupField to the Grid, and then add the BoundDataField to the newly created GroupField.

Is there a way to recursively search the grid for a GroupField by a GroupField key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a method similar to the following to search the grid for a GroupField:

```
public GroupField GetField(string key, GridFieldCollection columns)
{
    foreach (GridField column in columns)
    {
        if (column.GetType().Name == "GroupField")
        {
            GroupField gf = (GroupField)column;
            if (gf.Key == key)
                return gf;
            else
                return GetField(gf.Key, gf.Columns);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then, add the new column to the found GroupField, or if not found, create a new one

```
    GroupField gf = GetField("GroupField_0", WebDataGrid1.Columns);
    if (gf != null)
    {
        BoundDataField col = new BoundDataField();
        //set up new column here...
        gf.Columns.Add(col);
    }
    else 
    {
        GroupField groupField = new GroupField();
        //set up new group field here...
        WebDataGrid1.Columns.Add(groupField);
    }
```